# What is the best way store single-player rpg data on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, core-data

I want to store two type of data.
First is default immutable data set (like monster stats, item database)
Second is character stats to store data when user exit the app.

I'm already little programming using coredata(store sqlite default set on resources folder) for study. But I want exactly what is the best way store data consider memory, speed and encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large data i would suggest you to use CoreData or Sqilte ( there is a sqlite wrapper called FMDB that you might want to look.)

For more secure data such as stats scores i suggest you use Keychain ([sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797)).

For no secure small data you might use `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSArray *stringsArray = [[NSArray alloc] arrayWithObjects: string1, string2, string3, nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:stringsArray forKey:@"MyStrings"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit biased, but I prefer sqlite.  I whipped together some code examples that I used in some of my projects.  Let me know if you would like to see some other code examples.

```
//
//  SQLiteFunctions.h
//

#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "Users.h"

@interface SQLiteFunctions : NSObject
{
@public

@private
    char *error;
    sqlite3 *dbPointer;
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) Users *users;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *returnData;

-(BOOL)openBundleDatabase:(int)bibleversion;
-(void)closeDatabase;
-(int)getUserRecords:(const char *)sqlquery;

@end
```

**

```
//
//  SQLiteFunctions.m
//

#import "SQLiteFunctions.h"

@implementation SQLiteFunctions
@synthesize returnData;
@synthesize users;

-(BOOL)openBundleDatabase
{
    // initializing db file access
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.sqlite"];

    // testing to see if database was found
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        // can't find database
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        return NO;
    }

    // testing for other error
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dbPointer) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        // logging other error
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(dbPointer));
        return NO;
    }

    // returning success
    return YES;
}

-(void)closeDatabase
{
    // finalizing and closing the database
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
    sqlite3_close(dbPointer);
}

-(int)getUserRecords:(const char *)sqlquery
{
    // retreiving database values
    if ([self getRecords:sqlquery])
    {
        // setting the date format
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

        // looping through existing return rows
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            // retreiving database values
            users = [[Users alloc] init];

            // retreiving database values
            users.user_name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 0)];
            users.user_id = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement,1);
            users.last_logged = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)]];
            users.consecutive_days = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement,3);
            users.audio = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement,4);
            users.profile_skip = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement,5);
            users.anim_speed = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement,6);
            users.display_font = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 7)];

            // adding object to the return data array
            [returnData addObject:users];
        }
    }

    // returning number of rows in the array
    return [returnData count];
}
```

**

```
//
//  Users.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Users : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *user_name;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger user_id;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSDate *last_logged;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger consecutive_days;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL audio;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL profile_skip;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger anim_speed;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *display_font;

@end
```

**

```
//
//  Users.m
//

#import "Users.h"

@implementation Users
@synthesize user_name;
@synthesize user_id;
@synthesize last_logged;
@synthesize consecutive_days;
@synthesize audio;
@synthesize profile_skip;
@synthesize anim_speed;
@synthesize display_font;

@end
```